# Jquery effect on chrome extension pop up window?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

I'm new to making chrome extension. I was just trying to build some simple extension to get start. However I found that the popup window in the extension don't have any effect in jquery. Though some other functions work, the effect is not visible. Can anybody give me a clue on that?

Answer (score 0):

I ain't sure where you figured out `However I found that the popup window in the extension don't have any effect in jquery. Though some other functions work, the effect is not visible.`

Jquery can be used in popup window.

References

*a)* [jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js)

*b)* [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html)

*c)* [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

**Sample Demonstration**

***manifest.json***

Registered browser action in manifest file

```
{
    "name": "Jquery Demo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This demonstrates how Jquery works in popup",
    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html",
        "default_icon":"screen.png"
    }
}
```

***popup.html***

Used Js files a) Jquery b) custom file in suggested way to avoid inline scripting(CSP).

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="myjs.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

***myjs.js***

I used live function for demonstration you can use all supported functions here.

```
// You can use all methods of jquery here

//$(selector).live(events, data, handler);
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You are right, that's the same way how I add jquery. But if i want to add something like a 'slide' effect on a div, then it doesn't work.